# Maven project cannot resolve pom <parent>

Tags: maven

I have two maven projects in the same directory as follows:
- common
- rest-utils

rest-utils/pom.xml initially had the following  pom dependency:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

I was getting compile error when I ran **mvn clean**:

`[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for io.confluent:rest-utils-parent:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find io.confluent:common:pom:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT in https://myrepo.jfrog.io/myrepo/maven was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of au has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 8, column 13`

I added  to the  section:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../common/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
```

Now I am getting following error:

````
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' of POM io.confluent:rest-utils-parent:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/ahmedal-mehdi/projects/avro/rest-utils/pom.xml) points at io.confluent:common-parent instead of io.confluent:common, please verify your project structure @ line 8, column 13
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for io.confluent:rest-utils-parent:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find io.confluent:common:pom:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT in https://myrepo.jfrog.io/myrepo/maven was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of au has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 8, column 13
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project io.confluent:rest-utils-parent:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/ahmedal-mehdi/projects/avro/rest-utils/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for io.confluent:rest-utils-parent:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find io.confluent:common:pom:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT in https://myrepo.jfrog.io/myrepo/maven was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of au has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 8, column 13 -> [Help 2]```
````

Why is the warning and error mentioning **common-parent**.
Do I need to build the project **common** first.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: Can you explain what you exactly mean by `I have two maven projects in the same directory as follow` really two projects within the same directory?

Comment: They two separate repos in github that I cloned individually into the same directory (e.g. $HOME/download).  I cloned both since the pom file of `rest-utils` has a <parent> tag that includes the pom file of `common`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if `rest-utils` uses `common`, you need to build `common` first.

If they are part of a multi-module project, this will be done automatically for you.

Comment: `rest-utils` and `common` are two separate repos that I cloned individually.  I assumed "including" another pom file using `<parent>` tag is to leverage common properties defined in parent pom (`common`) in the child pom (`rest-utils`).  If that is the sole purpose of `<parent>`, is building `common` necessary.

Comment: A parent POM needs to be build before it is used.

Answer (score 0):

`rest-utils` looks for jars from `common` in the repos (including local repo). Performing `mvn install` in `common` first publishes the jars for `common` to the local repo.  Then I am able to compile/build. `rest-utils`.